# Make SQL Rows invisible with a query/code

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have an SQL database that I am interacting with via Java, I was wondering if there was an easy way to make a specific row hidden/invisible through Java other than just adding a "hidden" bit field to the table.

I want to be able to potentially toggle it to be visible again later.

e.g

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Geoff |

I want to have a line of code that will run so that only Bob will be visible as Geoff is hidden, but then be able to run a similar line of code and bring Geoff back into view. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to actually change the database somehow, or just make it so that your Java program doesn't display certain rows?

Comment: Preferably changing the database so that it wont show on SELECT * statements, but I am aware I could just add a bit field to make the java program not show the fields

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure that mySQL doesn't give you a built-in way of hiding rows.  I think the right thing to do is add a bit field.

Comment: You could use a VIEW with a condition, then query the view.